# Latex related community promotion ads

Tags: discussion

Would it be a good idea to have on the main site a box dedicated to Latex-related content/ads such as updates available on CTAN, interesting blogs, upcoming events?
It would be a bit more general than what is proposed in physics:

https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2810/community-promotion-ads-2013

It would be of the size of the current "community bulletin".